# difftime returning 0 when there is clearly a difference

Tags: c

I have the following C99 program which measures performance of simple division operations relative to addition. However, the `difftime` function keeps returning 0 even though the program is clearly taking several seconds to process `runAddition` and `runDivision` with `iterations` set to 1 billion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void runAddition(long long iterations)
{
    long long temp;
    for (long long i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)
    {
        temp = temp + i;
    }
}

void runDivision(long long iterations)
{
    long long temp;

    // Start at 1 to avoid division by 0!
    for (long long i = 1; i <= iterations; i++)
    {
        temp = temp / i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long iterations = 1000000000;
    time_t startTime;

    printf("How many iterations would you like to run of each operation? ");
    scanf("%d", &iterations);

    printf("Running %d additions...\n", iterations);
    startTime = time(NULL);
    runAddition(iterations);
    printf("%d additions took %f seconds\n", iterations, difftime(time(NULL), startTime));

    printf("Running %d divisions...\n", iterations);
    startTime = time(NULL);
    runDivision(iterations);
    printf("%d divisions took %f seconds\n", iterations, difftime(time(NULL), startTime));
}
```

Comment: It's good practise to start loops counting from 0 rather than 1.

Comment: Yes but did you see my comment? "Start at 1 to avoid division by 0"

Comment: Out of interest, did you try passing the startTime ref to time() - i.e. change startTime = time(NULL); to time(&startTime)? Not sure *why* that woudl help, they are both the same thing... just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your format string expects an `int` (`%d`), and a `double` (`%f`). Your arguments are `long long` and `double`. You should set the first format string as `%lld`.

When pushing arguments on the stack to call `printf`, you push a `long long` using 8 bytes, and a `double` using 8 bytes too. When the function `printf` reads the format string, it expects first an `int` on 4 bytes, and a `double` on 8 bytes. `printf` gets the `int` correctly as you are little-endian and the first four bytes of your `long long` are enough to represent the value. `printf` then gets the `double` for which it gets the last four bytes of the `long long`, followed by the first four bytes of the `double`. As the last four bytes of the `long long` are zeroes, what `printf` thinks is a double starts with four bytes with value zero, resulting in a very very tiny value for the `double` according to the binary representation of doubles.

Comment: Ahh... I had no idea that using an incorrect format specifier could affect the others. This fixed the problem, +1 and thanks. Also, could you explain this further at all or point me to some documentation?

Comment: Be careful because the format specifier for `long long` is CRT dependent. Better avoid printing longs.

Comment: @ruslik: that's what  [`stdint.h`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdint.h.html) and [`inttypes.h`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html) are for.

Comment: @Hasturkun @codaddict, both files are not found in Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. Looking into C++ standard, I find that long long is not supported in C++ standard 2003 (ISO/IEC 14882), but supported by C++ 0x draft (n3126). See section "Integer literals" of both documents

Comment: @Sheen: true, but as question did refer to C99 and not C++, it's still relevant

Comment: @Hasturkun, I didn't say question is irrelevant. I just state a fact. And more important fact is that Microsoft compiler doesn't have the standard C header files. Does it mean it is not universally portable? Any more portable way?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `%lld` in place of `%d` in the `printf`:

```
printf("%lld additions t
         ^^^
```

[**Works fine after this change.**](http://www.ideone.com/MXGT9)

Comment: @PigBen, Curious about this. Seems my long-standing assumption that larger integer will be truncated by printf() is not true ???

Comment: @Sheen -- In the old days, before long long existed, this was never a problem.  All integer types(char,short,int,long) would be upcast to long.  But now with the addition of long long, things are different.  I'm not sure exactly what the standard says about it, I don't use printf anymore, I prefer C++ streams.

Answer (score 1):

Make temp `volatile` so it does not get optimized away. The compiler is probably seeing it as a section/function with no side effects.

Comment: This is the most likely thing, in my opinion.

Comment: Don't think so.  "temp = temp / i" requires you to perform the calculation to determine the final value of temp.  You can't optimize it away.

Comment: Given the large number of iterations, and the function is inlined, temp would become 0 in about 30 or so iterations. Edit: Actually 30 is based on divide by 2 all the time. With increasing `i`, the number of iterations would even be less.

Answer (score 0):

It calculates the difference in seconds between time1 and time2. So maybe your time difference is less than 1 second?

Output your start and end time to verify.

Comment: No, it is definitely more than a second. More like 10 seconds. I've verified this by printing `startTime` and `time(NULL)`.

Comment: @Jake Petroules, can you output start and end time to debug?

Comment: Yes, as I stated, I did that.

Answer (score 0):

time() returns a time_t, which has a resolution of one second.

The time required for runDivision() is less than one second; one billion operations on a multi-GHz core will take less than a second.

Comment: Takes 40 seconds on my machine. As I stated, "the program is *clearly* taking several seconds to process".