# fprintf and difftime madness

Tags: c, printf, time-t

Searched for answer for this but couldn't find anything. The closest I could find was 
[difftime returning 0 when there is clearly a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041541/difftime-returning-0-when-there-is-clearly-a-difference) Which has a great explanation that has to do with how the arguments are pushed onto the stack and what the format expects, but I think my issue is different:

I've made as simple of an example as possible. Suppose I have the following code in C:

```
time_t starttime = time(NULL)
somefunction();
time_t newtime = time(NULL)

fprintf(stderr, "starttime %f and difftime %f\n", starttime, difftime(newtime, starttime));
fprintf(stderr, "difftime %f and starttime %f\n", difftime(newtime, starttime), starttime);
return 0;
```

And somefunction is some function that runs for 1 or 2 seconds. The output I get for this is:

```
starttime 2.000000 and difftime 0.000000
difftime 2.000000 and starttime 0.000000
```

I don't even know where to begin my question. Why is it when I swap the order, the outputted values are still the same? Furthermore, why is one of the values 0? This is the same whether I use %f, %d, %lu, %llu, etc. Is there a stack-argument explanation to this? What is fprintf really doing internally?

Thank you. I've wasted too much of my life trying to debug this and I really would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`starttime` is a `time_t`, but you're to print it with a `%f`, which expects a `double`.  Evidently, on your platform, `time_t` is some integer type instead.

Likely, your platform's calling convention for variable-argument-list functions like `fprintf()` passes floating point arguments in a different location from integer arguments.

The `difftime()` function is likely returning 2.0, which is being passed in the first floating-point argument location, which is why the first `%f` prints a 2.0 in both cases.  The second floating-point argument location appears to contain a zero, so the second `%f` prints a zero in both cases.  The `time_t` argument is being placed in a different location that isn't being examined by the `fprintf()` code at all.

Answer (score 2):

The `"%f"` specifier is not right for `time_t` on your platform. As far as I know the `time_t` type can be integral or real.

For example [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sys_types.h.html) merely says:

> `time_t` and `clock_t` shall be integer or real-floating types.

Try this:

```
/* Flawed bad and wrong. */
printf("%f\n", (double)starttime);
```

I have seen suggestions to cast it to `uintmax_t`, `unsigned long long` etc. Obviously, the real answer is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100106013002/http://freebsd.monkey.org/freebsd-ports/200601/msg00160.html):

> There is no uniform way to printf() time_t, period. You are not
>   supposed to do this - you're don't even need to know what a time_t is
>   internally. Suggested alternatives include ctime() and strftime().
>   Please use these to keep code portable.

Comment: it doesn't seem to matter what specifiers I use. What are you suggesting I use instead?

Comment: @bhh1988: the specifiers in the format string _must_ match the types of the variables you pass as arguments. The example cnicutar posted casts the `time_t` value to a double to be sure that they do match.